# forwardRef on Select does not save chosen value with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-forwardref

I am building a library of react components.

This text field works by passing a `ref` with `forwardRef`:

```
export const TextField = React.forwardRef((props:TextFieldProps, ref) => {

return (
    <input ref={ref}....
```

However when I try the same with a `select`:

```
export const SimpleSelect = React.forwardRef((props: SimpleSelectProps, ref: Ref<HTMLSelectElement>) => {

const options = props.options

return (
  <select ref={ref}  className="Select">
    <option>-- Select an option --</option>
    {options &&
      options.map((option: OptionsType) => (
        <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
          {option.label}
        </option>
```

And then I use [react-hook-form](/questions/tagged/react-hook-form) in my own app like this:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <SimpleSelect
    {...register('thingId', { required: true })}
    title="Thing"
    options={
      things &&
      things.map(({ thing }: Thing) => ({
        value: thing.uid,
        label: thing.primaryName,
      }))
    }
  />
```

The selected option does not save, and I can see this as when I submit the form, it tries to submit "-- Select an option --" even after choosing an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to spread the props provided by RHF in the `select` component to make your control works properly. Specifically, the `select` needs a `name` attribute so it can be identified and `onChange` so RHF can listen to the option changed event:

```
<select ref={ref} className="Select" {...props}>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: fantastic thanks

Comment: I never thought of that before! Thank you. Helps me a lot